# how to fire ifClicked event on Dyanamically Generated ichek chekbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

this is done nicely in static element but not dynamically checkbox
this is method of icheck check box.i want to called this method on dynamically generated ichekbox in jquery how?

[documentaion of icheck](https://github.com/fronteed/icheck)

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('ifChecked',function(event){
   /* do something */
});`]
```

Comment: how to get all cheked chekbox value using documentation of icheck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In newer versions of jquery, they deprecated LIVE which was the old way to accomplish that, now this is the new syntax for accomplishing what you are looking for.

```
$(document).on('ifChecked','input[type="checkbox"]',function(event){
/* do something */
});
```

Comment: how to get cheked value of all checkbox in icheck

Comment: loop through checked with EACH.
`$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
console.log($(this).val());
});
`